# C++ create new object in Method

Tags: c++

So my problem is that I want to create new object on given address.

```
MethodA()
{
   TreeNode* nodeResult = NULL;
   initObject(nodeResult);
   //nodeResult is NULL anyway
}
void initObject(TreeNode* obj)
{
    if(obj == NULL)
    {
        obj = new TreeNode();
    }
}
```

It seems like new object is created but deleted at the end of brackets of `initObject` method.

Comment: In addition to @pw94's correct answer, it's worth noting that the object hasn't been deleted in your code, you've just lost the pointer to it. If you call `new` in C++ to make an object, it won't be deleted until you call `delete` on a pointer it. Modern convention is to make use of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` to avoid having to do this manually as much as possible. Do read up on them and the memory management/ownership concepts behind them.

Comment: @MatthewWalton's comment should be added to one of the answers.

Comment: There is nothing special about pointers. If you consider `void initNumber(int x) { if (x == 0) x = 42; } void f() { int x = 0; initNumber(x); }`, you'll understand what happens.

Answer (score 6):

This fails because your `initObject` method wants to modify the caller's variable, but you are passing a copy of it. Change it to:

```
void initObject(TreeNode* &obj)
{
    if(obj == NULL)
    {
        obj = new TreeNode();
    }
}
```

This will give `initObject` function a *reference* to the caller's variable, and any assignment to it will be visible to the caller after function returns.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use reference because pointer is value type

```
MethodA()
{
   TreeNode* nodeResult = NULL;
   initObject(nodeResult);
   //nodeResult is NULL anyway
}
void initObject(TreeNode* & obj)
{
    if(obj == NULL)
    {
        obj = new TreeNode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what a pointer is.

A pointer is a variable storing the address of a memory block. Copying a pointer just copies the address.

Here:

```
obj = new TreeNode();
```

You give a new value to `obj`, the address of the new `TreeNode`, but that's it. You don't return it out of your function. And as the argument `TreeNode* obj` is a variable copy of `nodeResult`, which just stores an address, `nodeResult` itself isn't changed.

You can solve your problem by using a double pointer or a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)), like thus:

```
void initObject(TreeNode*& obj)
{
    if(obj == NULL)
    {
        obj = new TreeNode();
    }
}
```

Then what's passed to `initObject` isn't a copy of the `nodeResult` but a reference to the variable itself, making it modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

```
TreeNode* nodeResult = NULL;
```

Is a variable which contains a memory address.

When you call `initObject(nodeResult);` you pass the contents of that pointer which at that point are `NULL`. You need to pass the pointer it self so after the function call the variable has a valid value. IF you had an `int` instead of a `TreeNode*` you would pass the `int` either as a `&` or as a `*`. Similarly :

```
void initObject(TreeNode*& obj) // see it as int&
{
    if(obj == NULL)
    {
        obj = new TreeNode();
    }
}
```

or

```
void initObject(TreeNode* * obj) // see it as int*
{
    if(*obj == NULL)
    {
        *obj = new TreeNode();
    }
}
```